# Form access: 3265: item not found in this collection

Tags: ms-access

I have a code in the MS Access to put a attachment value in a field  to a Attachment box in form. But with my code, the error 3265 occur:

```
Function Attachment_show()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb

With Me.Recordset
.MoveFirst
Do While Not .EOF
Dim IDD As String
IDD = Me.ID.Value

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Tbl_Header.* FROM Tbl_Header WHERE 
(((Tbl_Header.ID)= " & IDD & "));")

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
Me![Attachment] = rs("Attacment").Value   --> Error 3265
End If

.MoveNext
Loop
End With

End Function
```

Please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed a letter? Try

```
rs("Attachment").Value
```